# how to clear ASP.net DropDownList show previous selected item

Tags: asp.net

please help me how to recover it. I used ddlHassection.Items.Clear(); but its not working properly.

```
using (var context = new SMAPPDBEntities())
{
     var addDept = new SMDepartment
     {
          DepartmentCode = txtDeptCode.Text,
          DepartmentName = txtDeptName.Text,
          UnitID= Convert.ToInt32( ddlUnitName.SelectedValue),
          Description = txtDeptDescription.Text,
          DepartmentHead = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDeptHeadName.SelectedValue),
          HasSection = Convert.ToBoolean(ddlHasSection.SelectedValue),
          Tag= txtDeptTag.Text
      };
      try
      {
           context.SMDepartment.Add(addDept);
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ex.ToString();
       }
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: has section dropdownlist is a databound field from database. Every  time when I add A department it saves previous items in the dropdownlist.

Comment: have tried with DDL1.ClearSelection(); that?

Comment: Please clear your question

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
}

or

DDL1.ClearSelection();
```